# Always reading the first row of the movies table

Tags: android, sqlite, android-contentprovider

I am doing the second part of Popular Movies project provided by Udacity. So far I managed to store everything trought a content provider. I have 4 tables.

- **settings**: Which stores the sorting order of the url(popularity, vote_average, revenue).

ie. [revenue url](https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?sort_by=revenue.desc&api_key=da9c52d611f8fc0d041fe4505d06ba0f)

- **reviews**
- **movies**: All 20 movies with images,titles etc. The link is similar as before.
- **trailers**: A table that contains youtube trailers with key values

ie [trailers](https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/346364/videos?api_key=da9c52d611f8fc0d041fe4505d06ba0f)

I can read all movies table rows and display images in a gridview. However, when I click on an image, I always read in the details activity, the details of the first row of the movies tables. Not the details of the clicked image.

I have uploaded the project in [github](https://github.com/theo82/PopularMoviesPart2) so you can run my project, and see where I am stuck.

Here is how I handle the item click part.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle onSavedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_activity, container, false);

    // The CursorAdapter will take data from our cursor and populate the ListView.
    mGridViewMoviesAdapter = new PosterAdapter(getActivity(), null, 0);

    // initialize the GridView
    GridView gridView =  rootView.findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    gridView.setAdapter(mGridViewMoviesAdapter);

    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
            // CursorAdapter returns a cursor at the correct position for getItem(), or null
            // if it cannot seek to that position.
            Cursor cursor = (Cursor) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position);
            if (cursor != null) {
                String locationSetting = Utility.getPreferredOrder(getActivity());
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), DetailsActivity.class)
                        .setData(MovieContract.MovieEntry.buildMovieSettingWithSetting(locationSetting));
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    });
    return rootView;
}
```

I have been trying this all weekend. Basically I follow the instructions from the [openweathermap](https://github.com/udacity/Sunshine-Version-2/tree/4.23_fix_settings/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/sunshine/app) project

Comment: I don't particularly wanna dig through your whole GitHub project to figure out the details, but you're always passing the same data to `DetailsActivity` in `onItemClick()`. Perhaps you should be getting `locationSetting` from the `Cursor`, instead of that `Utility` method; maybe something like `String locationSetting = cursor.getString(COL_SETTING);`. Otherwise, the `Cursor`, and specifically the record at that position, is never used there.

Comment: @Mike M. Thanks for the answer, I tried your solution, but the same problem persists.

Comment: @Mike String locationSetting = cursor.getString(COL_SETTING); and the                 String locationSetting = Utility.getPreferredOrder(getActivity()); return a string. WhenI  first start the app the string 'popularity' is returned which is correct. If I choose to display the movies with the highest revenues, then the string 'revenue' is returned. Perhaps the error is somewhere else, and can't see it.

Comment: @Mike. As I said in my original question, everything is stored into my sqlite db, as they should. But I always read the first table's row, after I click on a movie. Interesting error, but I am stuck in this one. haha.

Comment: So, what exactly do you expect to show in the `DetailsActivity`? The exact movie you select from the `GridView`? If so, I'm kinda confused, 'cause it doesn't seem that "popularity" or "revenue" or whatever would be what you want to pass on that `Intent`. Wouldn't you want to pass the unique ID for that movie?

Comment: @Mike M. Yes the exact movie I select from the gridview.

Comment: OK, then what you're passing there doesn't make a lot of sense. From a quick glance at your Provider, that URI will generate a query that returns all of the movies. `DetailsActivity` just happens to only grab the first one from that query, and so you get the same one each time. You should instead create a URI with the selected movie's ID - which you can get from the `Cursor` in `onItemClick()` - and modify the Provider to recognize and respond to such a URI (if it doesn't already) with just a single movie entry with that ID.

Comment: @Mike M. Ok I will try this instead.

Comment: @Mike Fixed. I also had to pass the image url string to the next activity. https://github.com/theo82/PopularMoviesPart2